# Pre loading objects in an HQL query

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm using the following HQL query to try and load a set of objects when I select a Student object based on the advice found at the following link.
http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernate-query-101/

```
from gradebook.model.Student student where student.studentId=1 left join fetch student.scores
```

I get the following error.
unexpected token: left near line 1, column 64 
I've pasted the relevant section of my mapping file below.

```
<set name="scores" inverse="true" lazy="true" table="score" fetch="select">
<key>
<column name="student_id" not-null="true" />
</key>
<one-to-many class="gradebook.model.Score" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HQL syntax is wrong. The JOIN clause belongs *before* the WHERE clause.

The HQL syntax is based on the SQL syntax. If you don't know SQL syntax very well, you may run into trouble with HQL syntax as well. I can recommend you the [SQL tutorial at w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl).

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, moving the join fixed the problem. APparently the syntax in the link I refferenced was wrong, my SQL is a bit rusty so I'll check out the tutorial link you posted.